# HTML encode blog post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 blog and the text is stored in the database with markup tags inside it, but when I show the post, I see the markup tags instead of the expected output. So instead of some bold text, I see **some text** in the blog post.

How can I get the text to become bold? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<%= str.html_safe %>
```

Comment: The tags dissappear from the text, but it doesn't turn the text into bold text or shows section breaks (due to <br> tags. I'm using haml like this:  %div= post.html_safe

Comment: Also a gem like redcloth is not working, it just shows the conversion into HTML redcloth makes, but not the actual result (bold, underlined, etc)